# Wordpress display post count for custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, shortcode

I have a custom post type created and a taxonomy with CPT plugin.
Using Elementor I created an archive page to show the posts from the taxonomies created.

I would like a shortcode to dynamically display the number of posts from each taxonomy.

For example I have post type AI-Tools with taxonomy best-ai-tools and over 30 categories under this taxonomy.

Thank you